# Combine multiple columns in all possible pairs of combinations

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation

I've got a matrix (say) `x` of presence/absence of some property for 33 different properties for 1.000 respondent. Data looks like this:

```
| P1| P2| P3| P4| P5| P6| P7| P8| P9| P10| P11| P12| P13| P14| P15| P16| P17| P18| P19| P19| P20| P21| P22| P23| P24| P25| P26| P26| P27|P28| P29| P30| P31| P32| P33
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|  0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0
|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|  0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0
|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|  0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0
|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|  0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0
|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|  0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|  0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0
|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|  0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0
|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|  0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|  0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0
|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   0|   0|   0|  0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   0
```

I want to create a data frame where all possible combinations of 33 columns are possible, having for each of the 1,000 respondents a 1 if in the original matrix `x` both columns had a `1` and `0`, otherwise.

For example, I would obtain the combination for the first and second columns of the original matrix with this code:

```
ifelse(x[,i] == 1 & x[,i+1] == 1, 1, 0)
```

I should end up with a data frame of 1,000 rows (numbers of respondents) and 528 variables, as this is the number of different pairs of combinations of the 33 columns in matrix `x`.

Is there an efficient way of achieving this in R?

Comment: Does the order of the elements in the resultant matrix matter? e.g. `1 1 0 0` vs `0 1 0 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn` to get the pairwise combination of column names, subset the columns, check whether the the elements of two columns are equal to 1, convert to numeric, and `cbind` it

```
res <- do.call(cbind, combn(colnames(df1), 2,
            FUN = function(x) list(+(df1[x[1]] & df1[x[2]]))))
dim(res)
#[1]  10 528
```

Comment: When I use the code I create a matrix with 528 columns, but only with one row of NAs.

Supposing I have this matrix (only with 10 observations):

    n <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=330)
    x <- matrix(n, nrow = 10, ncol = 33)
    P <- rep("P", 33)
    Q <- 1:33
    names <- paste0(P,Q)
    colnames(x) <- names
   
How should I apply your solution?

Comment: @Crimc The 1 row of NAs is not clear.  Perhaps you have some NA values in column?

Comment: @Crimc It would be the same except change 'df1' to 'x' and also use `,` for separating the row/column index for matrix i.e. `res <- do.call(cbind, combn(colnames(x), 2,
            FUN = function(y) list(+(x[,y[1]] & x[,y[2]]))));dim(res)
#[1]  10 528`